# Is there a Linux distribution using uclibc and has a full toolchain?

Tags: linux, gcc

I am going to build a program using uclibc. However, building uclibc is a little difficult in recent systems using glibc, so I am looking for a distribution that uses uclibc and contains compilers like gcc. Then I can directly build my program on that system. Ancient system is also OK.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest I can figure is Gentoo. Though be ready for some work.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Libc